# How to kill zombie cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm not sure if my question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952648/deleting-a-cookie-in-javascript-does-not-work-consistently) or not.

IE9 deletes this cookie after closing the browser (expected) but Chrome 12, Firefox 5, and Opera 11 do not.  (During testing of the example below, each browser was closed after clicking "Delete Account." They were then reopened after a short period of time and in all but IE9 the cookies were still there.)

**Use Case:** Cookie expires 1 year after last visit by user. Account deletion should remove the cookie.

**Question:**
(1/2) Why does IE9 do the right (expected) thing and the others do not?
(2/2) How can I ensure all browsers destroy this cookie?

**Example:**

*login.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Create Cookie Example</title>

        <script>
            function setCookie() {
                var expDate = new Date();
                expDate.setDate(expDate.getDate() + 365);
                document.cookie = "fakeCookie=" + escape("fake value")
                    + "; expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="setCookie()">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        <hr size="1" />
        <p><a href="profile.html">User Profile</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

*profile.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Delete Cookie Example</title>

        <script>
            function deleteConfirm() {
                if ( confirm("Are you sure you want to delete your account? "
                           + "All data will be lost; this action cannot be undone!")
                   ) deleteConfirmed()
                else return false

                return true;
            }

            function deleteConfirmed() {
                document.cookie = "fakeCookie=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>User Profile</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        <hr size="1" />
        <p><a href="index.html" onclick="return deleteConfirm()">Delete Account</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: The original post incorrectly identified login.html as index.html (forming a circular reference that would recreate the cookie when the "account" was deleted.)

Comment: +1, the title of your question could be a movie title :) PS: sorry for the off.topic

Comment: @meo I was thinking the same thing! Attack of the Zombie cookies that eat CPU cycles lol

Comment: `document.cookie = "whatever=;expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT"` deletes the cookie's value for me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_cookie

Comment: Your GMT-String is incorrect: `(new Date(0)).toUTCString();` => `Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`

Comment: @Robert: If I execute in a console the cookie is deleted; I don't understand what the difference is - it's the same code.

Comment: Have you tried setting `expires` to nothing? `document.cookie="fakeCookie=;expires=;";`

Comment: From the wiki: "Zombies would not seem that eerie and dreadful if you knew where they come from and how to eradicate them at their origins." Awesome.

Comment: Sorry for the noise folks.  I missed two semicolons in the if-else block of confirmDelete() function.  After switching debugging contexts in Opera (duh!) it complained... adding them in immediately fixed it.  Thanks all!

Comment: @psema4: can you mark this as answered and highlight the semicolon issue in your question?

Comment: Try '1970' instead of '70', just in case the naughty browsers are interpreting it as '2070'... we're too far past Y2K to still be using 2 digit years in any case.

Comment: @Marc B: Agreed!  Going with @Saxoier's suggestion to use toUTCString() instead.

Comment: If you've solved the problem please add and accept an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, psema4! On this site, we don't edit solved questions to include the answers or say "SOLVED." Instead, we add answers as separate answer posts. I've fixed it for you, this time.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: Not sure how to add an answer. The "Answer Your Question" button is all I can see to use, but it doesn't provide me with an interface to fill out an answer to accept.

Comment: Thanks @Lord Torgamus, much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The OP came up with this answer and initially edited it into the question. This is just a repost to keep the solution in an answer post, for semantics.*

```
        <script>
            function deleteConfirm() {
                if ( confirm("Are you sure you want to delete your account? "
                           + "All data will be lost; this action cannot be undone!")
                   ) deleteConfirmed(); // <-- ** MISSED SEMICOLON HERE **
                else return false;      // <-- ** AND HERE **

                return true;
            }

            function deleteConfirmed() {
                document.cookie = "fakeCookie=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";
            }
        </script>
```